# Applying fields/dtype to array representing points for sorting, then removing fields/dtype?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have an array which represents `(x, y, z)` points

```
x = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [2, 2, 1]
])
```

I would like to implement some ordering scheme onto these points using [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html). If I `sort` these points without implementing some specialized fields/dtype, `numpy` reorders the point's axes

```
x.sort(axis=0)
```

results in

```
[[0 1 0]
[0 1 0]
[1 1 0]
[1 2 1]
[2 2 1]
[2 2 1]]
```

Though, if I create a specialized `dtype` based on some field definition

```
point_dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)]
```

and define the array with this `dtype` then sort

```
point_dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)]
x = np.array([
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 2, 1),
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (2, 1, 0),
    (2, 2, 1)
], dtype=point_dtype)
x.sort(axis=0, order=['x', 'y'])
```

The result is an ordering of the points that makes sense

```
[(0., 1., 0.) (0., 2., 1.) (1., 1., 0.) (1., 2., 1.) (2., 1., 0.) (2., 2., 1.)]
```

---

The issue is that I already have my `x` from the example above defined, and it's quite large (`(18M, 3)`). I'm not quite sure how I can "apply" the `point_dtype` to this array so that I can `sort` it as described.

If I attempt to `astype` my array with the `point_dtype` then `numpy` seems to "unpack" each value in the array

```
point_dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)]
x = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 1],
    [2, 1, 0],
    [2, 2, 1]
])
x = x.astype(point_dtype)
```

results in `x` looking like

```
 [[(0., 0., 0.) (1., 1., 1.) (0., 0., 0.)]
 [(0., 0., 0.) (2., 2., 2.) (1., 1., 1.)]
 [(1., 1., 1.) (1., 1., 1.) (0., 0., 0.)]
 [(1., 1., 1.) (2., 2., 2.) (1., 1., 1.)]
 [(2., 2., 2.) (1., 1., 1.) (0., 0., 0.)]
 [(2., 2., 2.) (2., 2., 2.) (1., 1., 1.)]]
```

instead of

```
[(0., 1., 0.) (0., 2., 1.) (1., 1., 0.) (1., 2., 1.) (2., 1., 0.) (2., 2., 1.)]
```

**How can I retroactively apply a specialized `dtype` to a pre-existing `numpy` array?**

I've inspected the documentation for [`numpy.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), though none of the possible parameters seem to address this situation. I've also found the `numpy` documentation for [structured arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html), though again, nothing there seems to address retroactively applying a `dtype`.

Further, **how can I remove this `dtype` to get the "raw" array representation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *view* to efficiently create an objec that shares the underlying buffer:

```
>>> x = np.array([
...     [0, 1, 0],
...     [0, 2, 1],
...     [1, 1, 0],
...     [1, 2, 1],
...     [2, 1, 0],
...     [2, 2, 1]
... ], dtype=np.float64)
>>> x
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 2., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 2., 1.],
       [2., 1., 0.],
       [2., 2., 1.]])
>>> point_dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)]
>>> x.view(point_dtype)
array([[(0., 1., 0.)],
       [(0., 2., 1.)],
       [(1., 1., 0.)],
       [(1., 2., 1.)],
       [(2., 1., 0.)],
       [(2., 2., 1.)]], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

Note, the view is an independent *python object*:

```
>>> x is view
False
```

But it shares the same underlying buffer:

```
>>> x[0,0] = 99
>>> view
array([[(99., 1., 0.)],
       [( 0., 2., 1.)],
       [( 1., 1., 0.)],
       [( 1., 2., 1.)],
       [( 2., 1., 0.)],
       [( 2., 2., 1.)]], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
>>>
```

Another approach is simply to modify the dtype of your original object:

```
>>> x.dtype = point_dtype
>>> x
array([[(99., 1., 0.)],
       [( 0., 2., 1.)],
       [( 1., 1., 0.)],
       [( 1., 2., 1.)],
       [( 2., 1., 0.)],
       [( 2., 2., 1.)]], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
>>> x.dtype = np.float64
>>> x
array([[99.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Possibly while I have your attention. I am running into an issue with my array `points` with the following characteristics [`points.shape:  (18928298, 3)  dtype:  float64  type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  points[0, :]:  [ 2.72499860e+05  3.28972911e+06 -1.54100000e+01]`]. // When I attempt to generate the `view` with `points_view = points.view(dtype=[('x', points.dtype), ('y', points.dtype), ('z', points.dtype)])` or even hardcoding the `dtype` as just `np.float64` I receive "When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array."

Comment: As far as I can tell I am following the same pattern as with the example you provided. The only difference is that `x` is defined explicitly, while my `points` is created through various `hstack` and `vstack` after loading some data files. // Does this have to do with how the memory of the `points` (or in the example `x`) is laid out?

Comment: Ahh. This seems to have been the issue. I fixed the issue by `points = points.astype(points.dtype, order='C')`

Answer (score 2):

`np.lexsort` does what you want (I think):

```
In [23]: np.lexsort((x[:,1],x[:,0]))
Out[23]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [24]: x[_,:]
Out[24]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1]])
```

---

Recent numpy versions added a `unstructured_to_structured` function that's supposed to make creating a structured array easier.  It does not, though make a view.

```
In [40]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [41]: X = rf.unstructured_to_structured(x,  np.dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')]))
In [42]: X
Out[42]: 
array([(0., 1., 0.), (0., 2., 1.), (1., 1., 0.), (1., 2., 1.),
       (2., 1., 0.), (2., 2., 1.)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
In [43]: X.sort(order=['x','y'])
In [44]: X
Out[44]: 
array([(0., 1., 0.), (0., 2., 1.), (1., 1., 0.), (1., 2., 1.),
       (2., 1., 0.), (2., 2., 1.)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```