# Sort multi-dimensional string array descending without changing original array order in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting, multidimensional-array

have got an array like below:

```
x = array([['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP']], dtype=object)
```

I'm trying to sort this multi-dimensional array w.r.t. 4th element `x[:,3]` which is a string(this will be always either '`PP`' or '`Loose`') in descending order ***without changing the original row order***.

**Tried code:**

```
x[x[:,3].argsort()][::-1]       #but this shuffles the original array row order within 4th element which should not happen
```

**Expected Output:**

```
x = array([['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list sort with just a sort key which compares if 4th element is "Loose".

Stability of python `sort` guarantees that it's not going to move elements around if not needed.

```
lst = [['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP']]

lst = sorted(lst,key=lambda x:x[3]=='Loose')
print(lst)
```

prints:

```
[['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'], 
['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'], 
['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'], 
['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'], ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
 ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose']]
```

This is a non-numpy solution, but it works. Then convert back to numpy array: `array(lst)`

Comment: Here is an alternative solution for a similar issue I had faced in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977929/applying-fields-dtype-to-array-representing-points-for-sorting-then-removing-fi // This may help if you want to extend the sorting to multiple keys.

Comment: option 1 returns a new list(instead of array) in expected order but we need an array and option 2 doesn't work as it shuffles the original order

Comment: a little change to option 1 works. converting it back to array with np.array(). Thanks for you help :)

Comment: yes! not fully satisfactory but works

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather silly/inefficient to go from NumPy to Python back to NumPy like the previous answers. NumPy has stable sorting as well, you just need to ask for it:

```
x[x[:,3].argsort(kind='stable')]
```

Note I removed your reversal for now. The result is:

```
[['Lemon' 0.25 0.75 'Loose']
 ['Orange Navel' 0.25 0.75 'Loose']
 ['PP Mango' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['PP Nectarine' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['PP Peach' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['PP Cherries' 0.25 0.75 'PP']]
```

Now how do we get 'PP' before 'Loose'? One way is to compare the column with 'Loose' like Jean-François [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75324384/12671057), as that turns 'Loose' into True and 'PP' into False, and False is less than True:

```
x[(x[:,3] == 'Loose').argsort(kind='stable')]
```

Alternatively check **in**equality with 'PP':

```
x[(x[:,3] != 'PP').argsort(kind='stable')]
```

Both return your desired result:

```
[['PP Mango' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['PP Nectarine' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['PP Peach' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['PP Cherries' 0.25 0.75 'PP']
 ['Lemon' 0.25 0.75 'Loose']
 ['Orange Navel' 0.25 0.75 'Loose']]
```

Yet another way would be to fetch the 'PP' rows, fetch the non-'PP' rows, and vstack them:

```
PP = x[:, 3] == 'PP'
np.vstack((x[PP], x[~PP]))
```

What if you had more than two different values, or unknown values, so the (in)equality comparison trick doesn't suffice? How to do a stable reverse sort then? NumPy *doesn't* have a nice `reverse=True` like Python does. But we can do the same as what Python does to actually implement that. It reverses both before and after the actual sort. One way to do that in NumPy:

```
x[~x[::-1,3].argsort(kind='stable')[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNb8IwDIbv@RXeqY1Uqm1omoSUE1cGuVc5hOLRAk2iJCB62V/v3I9dEBNEkaPY7/s4jmtjZc286769bcCcG9dC3TjrI2jvdcumy1jRAYxj7ApirKZFkUgJX9rsbZLBa/7@0cdPipRPVMZgXINsjWXUvjb4QLrCxppbzcragLdEibqsHtA2nl6HsNYXPD0FXVbofY3hHldlsIutQ2G3B5qGM@ZooJheC9qLbK5AiD8sz7XfB/q89FibnUhC1NsTpdUd14sY@M9YfsiymL2R6x/xUFa9hYYR0HeA6WHUYuIYl1/IUB5TQkpJcxGZTs551/0C) (all four solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark of the posted solutions, both on your example array as well as a large array (100000 randomly chosen rows from your example). With time and memory usage:

```
6 rows:
Kelly_revrev    4.2 μs ± 0.1 μs       5,424 bytes 
Puff            4.7 μs ± 0.1 μs         961 bytes 
Jean_François   4.9 μs ± 0.2 μs         961 bytes 
Kelly_Loose     6.0 μs ± 0.1 μs       5,424 bytes 
Kelly_PP        6.0 μs ± 0.2 μs       5,424 bytes 
Kelly_vstack   11.3 μs ± 0.2 μs       2,568 bytes 

100000 rows:
Kelly_PP       11.9 ms ± 0.1 ms   4,002,328 bytes 
Kelly_vstack   12.2 ms ± 0.3 ms   6,500,512 bytes 
Kelly_Loose    12.5 ms ± 0.4 ms   4,002,328 bytes 
Kelly_revrev   37.7 ms ± 1.1 ms   4,002,328 bytes 
Jean_François  71.5 ms ± 1.2 ms  13,700,112 bytes 
Puff           71.8 ms ± 0.7 ms  13,700,112 bytes 

Python: 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:48:28) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2)]
NumPy:  1.15.4
```

I don't know why my NumPy solutions take more memory than the others for your small example but less for the large array. I guess the NumPy ones have some small constant overhead.

Full code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZXNbts4EMfveorZk6VA1VprpAUE6FSgh91uqkMPBQRDYKxRokakBJJyrQ3S19lz73vave8rpTMUldhpi8Yw/MGZ@fE/w@FomOx1rzb3960cem1BjXKYQBhQQ9DoXoJtJbYWvLnGRoydrXhVsxv/mB2NFbY1tt2ZxVmiUDGt17gP/JLVYodSdF2/c9FyMZjJBAHR4Q/suql62/cGw0OUBUAvjXbUCg5leCizeLOFPIeVc1lFidBXhgjhTavqfEUqLjta3h7TiuLHqF8IVRTP42jc0/tb1mdiZS9Swv2A4szbE9aebLubB1ZRQA4sCXx6pOl4EzUkPoKEF8U25m3pO4pm6O9U6@qNFuq/v/vWPJVI0UJrMYWsDevwEMMNTnkn5GUt4JAR7LSqnlqMTfNMFngYdihR2Wz5QeCYQveoDebv9YjMDppRUZ/kx6cdPxxWfFLu@KRg8ZNMY6eRiAeiPUgrS6of/CnUVb@KYZ38ds6fr@iT67qNXT70cm4XuLNCtwp/4voWZa@e@sz1ekIsUOyuf0J7RxlcIVyIPXbPgr6@Rq1bNN/jUolrOw2Y95cfKRuq8AfXTlQQ2qbupftqlQ0PibkWA5ZrCjHtX5in67Oz8yiGzHenRWP5TDUOVNxRtZYcd6JD1wV83fncbpsMyi00vYYGWgXuPO/IgRE8CUzY@Lax7F9aOJsxLsZyjO8fhyybLV2Sc7oiR53WrG55hITWRNl5kjZ3cMt67uDfL3DrxoozbY5Mq4AAvIPmHVyJw3TtleBhoOKQmoteoVs51Z/5erMLqwojv8Bu1SOQSxMtzqzW0EikGL4qC8InlYhhQFWH4cyDF2Aj@NUVd3Ftm0VYa5yy7FHojPaOwhikSRku@@Xej0ZX15FWchs0n3GHipRQa@j@k8lWUXCUqC@6y3e@uO60fDo1dsd7WpmQlaZZFHw/0QHFDRdLJldIDwUe7nUl6Z7oKYzKdPtI6QcPmSU2SVUpIbGqku7jSB2XbqL4oXFiPnpmZ2ka38HlRE0JLo85mnJd2jRdr9eU6f//8L1I8WU0Wz7QH1qW8@qGAubIVeGedxkt0xMn4anU9iparBejLKYMyEo3p6q8uaqi@/uv)):

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as time
from statistics import mean, stdev
import tracemalloc as tm
import sys

def Kelly_Loose(x):
    return x[(x[:,3] == 'Loose').argsort(kind='stable')]

def Kelly_PP(x):
    return x[(x[:,3] != 'PP').argsort(kind='stable')]

def Kelly_revrev(x):
    return x[~x[::-1,3].argsort(kind='stable')[::-1]]

def Kelly_vstack(x):
    PP = x[:, 3] == 'PP'
    return np.vstack((x[PP], x[~PP]))

def Jean_François(x):
    return np.array(sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[3] == 'Loose'))

def Puff(x):
    return np.array(sorted(x, key= lambda element: element[3], reverse=True))


funcs = Kelly_Loose, Kelly_PP, Kelly_revrev, Kelly_vstack, Jean_François, Puff


x = np.array([['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP']], dtype=object)

X = x[np.random.randint(x.shape[0], size=10**5), :]

def test(x, reps, unit, scale):
  times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
  def stats(f):
    ts = [t * scale for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} {unit} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} {unit}'

  for r in range(10):
    expect = None
    for f in funcs:
      t = time()
      for _ in range(reps):
        result = f(x)
      times[f].append((time() - t) / reps)
      if expect is None: expect = result
      assert (result == expect).all()

  print(len(x), 'rows:')
  for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    del result
    tm.start()
    result = f(x)
    peak = tm.get_traced_memory()[1]
    tm.stop()
    print(f.__name__.ljust(13), stats(f), f'{peak:11,} bytes ')
  print()

test(x, 1000, 'μs', 1e6)
test(X, 1, 'ms', 1e3)

print('Python:', sys.version)
print('NumPy: ', np.__version__)
```

Comment: Surprizing is that vstack wins slightly at the large array but is three times slower on a small one.   I had run the code myself (Python 3.9, numpy 1.23.4):. Kelly_PP wins clearly on 100000 rows with 5.3 and vstack with 8.1 is third. On a small array vstack with 15.3 is four times slower than the winner revrev with  3.7. In other words the result differs from that given above.

Comment: Could you paste your whole results into tio (or elsewhere) and share the link? I'd like to see the whole picture.

Comment: I added version infos, slightly changed the results.

Comment: See my answer here for the requested whole results.

Answer (score 0):

Following the request for providing full results of the tests below what can't be posted as a comment, so it is posted as an answer:

In order to get a fair comparison of the sort timings below the results for all the methods, but with code a bit changed, so the pure Python methods don't need to convert from numpy forth and back. It seems that numpy is maybe not the right way to go for such tasks in case of small arrays.

What is still a surprise for me is that the Kelly_vstack does not win the Kelly versions at 100000 rows and really sucks at 6 rows.

```
6 rows:
Puff            1.0 μs ± 0.0 μs         304 bytes 
Jean_François   1.1 μs ± 0.0 μs         304 bytes 
Kelly_revrev    3.8 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,624 bytes 
Kelly_Loose     7.2 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,582 bytes 
Kelly_PP        7.2 μs ± 0.1 μs       5,582 bytes 
Kelly_vstack   15.9 μs ± 0.1 μs       2,964 bytes 

100000 rows:
Kelly_PP        6.1 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Kelly_Loose     6.2 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Kelly_vstack    8.6 ms ± 0.0 ms   6,500,528 bytes 
Puff           14.9 ms ± 0.0 ms   1,865,936 bytes 
Jean_François  17.2 ms ± 0.1 ms   1,867,808 bytes 
Kelly_revrev   27.1 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 

Python: 3.9.13 (main, May 20 2022, 21:21:14) 
[GCC 5.4.1 20160904]
numpy 1.23.4
```

The timings with forth and back conversion to numpy are as follows:

```
6 rows:
Kelly_revrev    4.0 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,624 bytes 
Puff            4.7 μs ± 0.0 μs       1,120 bytes 
Jean_François   4.8 μs ± 0.0 μs       1,120 bytes 
Kelly_PP        7.0 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,582 bytes 
Kelly_Loose     7.1 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,582 bytes 
Kelly_vstack   15.7 μs ± 0.1 μs       2,964 bytes 

100000 rows:
Kelly_Loose     5.7 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Kelly_PP        5.8 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Kelly_vstack    8.2 ms ± 0.0 ms   6,500,528 bytes 
Kelly_revrev   26.2 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Puff           67.3 ms ± 0.9 ms  18,399,968 bytes 
Jean_François  69.1 ms ± 0.1 ms  18,399,968 bytes
```

showing that the forth and back conversion performs comparable well for small arrays as the numpy solution.

To get really the full view on the subject below the timings using the pure Python in-place sorting with `.sort()` instead of `sorted()` showing smaller differences in the timing of pure Python versions in case of a really very huge array when compared to numpy along with excellent timing for a small array (4 times faster than best numpy version):

```
6 rows:
Puff            0.9 μs ± 0.0 μs         208 bytes 
Jean_François   1.0 μs ± 0.0 μs         208 bytes 
Kelly_revrev    3.9 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,624 bytes 
Kelly_PP        7.0 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,582 bytes 
Kelly_Loose     7.2 μs ± 0.0 μs       5,582 bytes 
Kelly_vstack   15.2 μs ± 0.1 μs       2,964 bytes 

100000 rows:
Kelly_PP        6.2 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Kelly_Loose     6.3 ms ± 0.0 ms   4,002,456 bytes 
Kelly_vstack    8.4 ms ± 0.1 ms   6,500,528 bytes 
Puff            9.2 ms ± 0.0 ms     800,208 bytes 
Jean_François  11.4 ms ± 0.0 ms     800,208 bytes 
Kelly_revrev   27.6 ms ± 0.1 ms   4,002,456 bytes
```

Below the full code used to obtain the above results which could be easily adapted to show timings for sorting with and without Python/numpy conversions:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as time
from statistics import mean, stdev
import tracemalloc as tm

def Kelly_Loose(x):
    return x[(x[:,3] == 'Loose').argsort(kind='stable')]

def Kelly_PP(x):
    return x[(x[:,3] != 'PP').argsort(kind='stable')]

def Kelly_revrev(x):
    return x[~x[::-1,3].argsort(kind='stable')[::-1]]

def Kelly_vstack(x):
    PP = x[:, 3] == 'PP'
    return np.vstack((x[PP], x[~PP]))
"""
def Jean_François(x):
    return np.array(sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[3] == 'Loose'))

def Puff(x):
    return np.array(sorted(x, key=lambda element: element[3], reverse=True))
"""
def Jean_François(x):
    return sorted(x, key=lambda x: x[3] == 'Loose')

def Puff(x):
    return sorted(x, key=lambda element: element[3], reverse=True)
"""
def Jean_François(lst):
    lst.sort(key=lambda row: row[3]=='Loose')
    return lst

def Puff(lst):
    lst.sort(key=lambda row: row[3], reverse=True)
    return lst
#"""

funcs = Kelly_Loose, Kelly_PP, Kelly_revrev, Kelly_vstack, Jean_François, Puff

x = np.array(
      [['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP']], dtype=object)
X = x[np.random.randint(x.shape[0], size=10**5), :]
#print(len(X)) 

lst = [['PP Mango', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['PP Nectarine', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Lemon', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Peach', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP'],
       ['Orange Navel', 0.25, 0.75, 'Loose'],
       ['PP Cherries', 0.25, 0.75, 'PP']]
LST = (10**5//6)*lst+lst[0:4]
#print(len(LST))

def test(x, reps, unit, scale):
  bckpX = x
  times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
  def stats(f):
    ts = [t * scale for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} {unit} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} {unit}'

  for r in range(10):
    expect = None
    for f in funcs:
      # """
      if f in [Jean_François, Puff]:
          if reps==1:
              x = LST
          else:
              x = lst
      else:
          x = bckpX
    #"""
      t = time()
      for _ in range(reps):
        result = f(x)
      times[f].append((time() - t) / reps)
      #if expect is None: expect = result
      #assert (result == expect).all()

  print(len(x), 'rows:')
  #print(funcs)
  for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    del result
    # """
    if f in [Jean_François, Puff]:
        if reps==1:
            x = LST
        else:
            x = lst
    else:
        x = bckpX
    #"""
    tm.start()
    result = f(x)
    peak = tm.get_traced_memory()[1]
    tm.stop()
    print(f.__name__.ljust(13), stats(f), f'{peak:11,} bytes ')
  print()

test(x, 1000, 'μs', 1e6)
test(X,    1, 'ms', 1e3)
import sys
print('Python:', sys.version)
print('numpy', np.version.version)
```

Comment: Sorry, but... they have a NumPy array as input and want a NumPy array as output. Presumably because the rest of their program benefits from using NumPy. The pure Python solutions don't get to cheat by disregarding the conversions from NumPy and back. That's misleading.

Comment: Hmmm ... The accepted answer proposes usage of the pure Python version, suggesting that the pure Python version is OK for OPs purpose, else it won't be accepted. In case of small arrays with content like posted in the question numpy is probably really not the right tool to use, so if at all, only one conversion to Python list would be needed.

Comment: I'm btw not surprised that the NumPy versions suck for tiny data. That's just not what NumPy is for. I've seen that in other cases before, where NumPy operations had a relatively large constant overhead. I don't know why, I guess it's because it's third-party code that needs to interact with Python via some interface. Or maybe NumPy takes extra time to do things that pay off for large data, which is what it's for. I included their original tiny example in my test because it's the original, but I wouldn't focus on that. Likely their real data *is* large, or else they wouldn't be using NumPy.

Comment: Well, that answer was accepted when there was no working NumPy solution here yet. And note the OP's comments under it, complaining about the list result, saying they need an array, and saying that they're converting back to array. I think it was just the best they got back then. At least it worked at all.

Comment: Hmm, might've even been the only answer back then. I actually like Puff's better. That's really "sorting in descending order". Not just "put 'Loose' at the end". I actually wrote my revrev solution first, which is also a general sorting. But then while writing my answer about it, JF's answer and it being accepted made me think the OP's example isn't just reduced to two different values in order to have a nice example, but that they actually only have those two values in their real data. So I added some solutions for that. Oh well. </rambling>

Comment: I think that a fraction of a microsecond of computation time is not really worth the effort of optimization, so it's just unnecessary neat peaking. What surprises me is that pure Python seem to suck at very large array/list. My up to now experience was that Python sorting was superior to the numpy one. I think it depends also highly on the content of the array, so reliable timing of sorting is not really possible because the timings will be reversed in some cases of sorted data compared to another data. In other words it all is pointless discussion. Who cares?

Comment: I just noticed the other results you added, thanks. I'd put the with-conversions times first, as that reflects the question as asked, but ok. Btw I saw your ["the actual question is"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75328513/sudoku-board-validator-loop-through-every-n-item-in-couple-lists/75329232#comment132923492_75328513) complaint. It's something that often bugs me as well. (Though in that case, I find it ok, it was just someone asking whether the OP is interested in widening the question to allow their answer, they didn't just go ahead and post that answer.)

Comment: Do you have an example where Python sorting was superior to NumPy?

Comment: I decided to stop investing time here ... so I won't go tor the example and the long discussion about the influence of the data on the sorting timing and the differences depending on data size and structure. Timing of sorting requires usually a very wide range of different real-world-case datasets and the timing order of different methods rank other way for some datasets compared to another ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251589/discussion-between-claudio-and-kelly-bundy).

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use a sorting key, i.e. specify what the sorting algorithm is oging to comapre when trying to sort the elements of your array. Here you want the key to be the last element of each row, so:

```py
np.array(sorted(x, key= lambda element: element[3], reverse=True))
```

should give you your desired output. Note the use of `reverse=True` to get the data in reversed order.